# Conditional structures, R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, structure

I am a new user on R.

I have a datafame like:

```
  Month    eqqBio    eqqLi   ..........
 January    20       20000
February   100       500
   .
   .
   .
```

The 2 columns, eqqBio and eqqLi are the % compared to the previous year.
My aim is if the % compared to the previous year is 1000(or +) you flag it or a message indicating an outlier.
It's just I don't understant the conditional structure, and I don't know how I have to proceed..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are the previous year's values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(Month = c("January", "February"),
                 eqqBio = c(20, 100),
                 eqqLi  = c(20000, 500))
df$alert <- df$eqqBio > 1000 | df$eqqLi > 1000
```

That gives you a new column. If both eqqBio and eqqLi are below 1000 the value in the according row is FALSE. Otherwise it is TRUE.

Of you have more than 2 columns you can do it like this:

```
# sample data
df <- data.frame(Month = c("January", "February", "March"),
                 eqqBio = c(20, 100, 0),
                 eqqLi  = c(20000, 500, 0),
                 dummy1 = c(0, 0, 1001),
                 dummy2 = c(0, 0, 0))
# Check is any values in this row are > 1000 but only check columns 2:5.
df$alert <- apply(df[, 2:5], 1, function(x) any(x > 1000))
```

Adjust the columns you wish to include by changing `2:5` in `df[, 2:5]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But if I have a thousand of column, am i supposed to mark a thousand of number ?

Comment: Just to make sure: do I get that right that you have a thousand columns and you want to know if a value is greater than 1000 in ANY of them? If that is the case you want one flag to mark this row?

Comment: It's, if I have a thousand of columns and rows, do I have a quick way to check without writing every numbers like " c(20, 100,......) ?

Comment: It's perfect @Jan! And to have one flag to mark this row?

Comment: You have the new `df$alert`column that is `TRUE` if any value in the row is greater than 1000. You cn use it to get only the rows < 1000 with `df[df$alert, ]` and the opposite with `df[-which(df$alert), ]`. What else do you need?

Comment: Thanks @Jan! You are great! I don't think I need anything else. I will improve my comprehension on R. Thanks for your help.